# Issue concernig the continue keyword in a do while loop

Tags: c

For a project, I need to ask the user to enter two numbers
If the first input (Line) is bad, the program must ask again for the line
If the second input is bad (Matches), the program must ask again for both line and matches.

I tried to make a `do while` loop but even after a few tries it doesn't work like I want.

Do you have some clues to make this loop works as intended?

`ask_number()` is a function that ask for a number from `stdin`, it takes a prompt in parameter and `return` the number or 0 if the string is not numeric only

`check_line()` and `check_matches()` check if the input is correct.

`my_putstr()` is explicit.

`gamestate` contains information for the check_ functions

```
int player_turn(gamestate_t *gamestate)
{
    int line = 0;
    int matches = 0;

    my_putstr("Your turn:\n");
    do {
        line = ask_number("Line: ");
        if (check_line(line, gamestate)) {
            matches = ask_number("Matches: ");
        }
        else {
            line = 0;
            continue;
        }
    } while (!check_matches(line, matches, gamestate));
    return (0);
}
```

If you entered a bad input for the line the function exits.
However, if you enter a good number for line then a bad number for matches the program works as intended including if you enter a bad line number.

Comment: So, what is your question, exactly?

Comment: `continue;` serves no purpose where you have placed it in your code. There are no subsequent expressions avoided by issuing `continue;` at that point. Simply setting `line = 0;` alone is equivalent.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I want to skip the call to check_matches(), but apparently continue does not skip the condition in a do while. Do yopu have an idea about how I can skip the call to check_matches() when check_line() returned false ?

Comment: Yes, take input in a continual loop (e.g. `for (;;) { /* do input, break when good input */ }`

Comment: It solves my problem, thank you !
Do you think it is compliant with the kernel coding style (my school wants student to respect a codings tyle very simialr to the kernel one) ?

Comment: An adequately spaced, clean coding style is all you need. The kernel style has a few quirks. 4-space indent for levels, and adequate/proper spacing around `function (param, param)` and `if (a < b)`. Place the opening `{` on the same line after `struct` definitions and with internal code blocks, on the next line for `function` definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you would need the `continue` keyword here. You can simply have a boolean value that is initialized to 0 in the beginning and then only break out of the loop once you have satisfied both conditions (i.e. you get a valid input for both `line` and `matches`) by setting the boolean variable to 1.

```
int player_turn(gamestate_t *gamestate)
{
    int line = 0;
    int matches = 0;
    int bFound = 0;      //boolean variable indicating whether both values have been found

    my_putstr("Your turn:\n");
    do {

        line = ask_number("Line: ");
        if (check_line(line, gamestate)) {
            matches = ask_number("Matches: ");

            if (check_matches(line, matches, gamestate)) {
                bFound = 1;     //both inputs were valid, so set boolean variable to true and break out of loop
            }
            else {
                line = 0;
            }
        }
    } while(!bFound);

    return 0;
}
```

If you look at the code above, if the first input fails, then your program will not proceed to ask for the input to `matches` but instead prompts the user to re-enter the value for `line`.

If the second input fails, then the program resets `line` to 0 and the loop then restarts over to ask to enter a value for `line` again. If both values are valid, then set `bFound` to 1 (TRUE) and break out of the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I used a continous loop (`for(;;)`)and break but your solution is good too

Comment: I think this answer serves the purpose only in that it offers an alternative to make the program work. It doesn't help @Magikh42 with his (apparently wrong) understanding of what `continue` does: it doesn't jump to the beginning of the loop (which is what he probably assumed), but just passes control directly to the conditional test.